# Date format - @ symbol has unexpected behaviour

Tags: views, datetime

I created a date format , then added that date format to a field within a view. But the `@` symbol is automatically appending to the end of the date format (even though i specified it to go into the middle of the date format, and is reflected correctly in the preview). I used [PHP:date - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) as my reference.

My date format: `l, F j @ g:ia` and it displays as: `Wednesday, June 17 @ 4:32pm`

Now when I select that date format for my date field within my view, it outputs the said date as: `Wednesday, June 17 4:32pm @`.

I'm confused because whenever I have put other characters before, it always outputted what I wanted. I've also tried using the html equivalent of `&#64;` but it outputs the @ symbol at the end of the format as well.

I'm just wondering if this is a <del>`views`</del>, `php`, or `date` issue? And is there anyway I can output this date as: `Wednesday, June 17 @ 4:32pm` from a date format?

Comment: Have you tried to use this date format anywhere else? Like content-type field? If so, what was the result? If no, why not?

Comment: @Mołot Yes I have, same behavior.

Comment: So at least it's not views :)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and was able to get this working by escaping the @ symbol.

Example: 'M j, Y \@ G:i'